# Populating img src from a PHP script after it fetches MySQL data (VS Node/Mongo Node/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, mongodb

I have a PHP script that checks which category an image belongs to (sports, entertainment etc.) Each image is linked to a specific category in the DB. Each image ID is the md5 of the image's byte64.

The process of serving the image looks like:

- PHP web page with the image has an `img` tag with a `src` tag that looks like `example.com/image-category.php?url=/img/some-photo.png`

PHP script:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

- PDO connection to MySQL, get image category, and if it's for instance "sports" as I want, then it's shown, else nothing is shown

readfile($whatever_img_url_we_want);
```

If there are 20 images on the page, that's 20 calls to the script, thus 20 db connections each time. This doesn't seem so optimal.

Got some questions that I need to be enlightened on...

- What could I do using this PHP/MySQL tech stack to optimize this?
- Do you think using a different tech stack for example Node with a db such as MySQL or Mongo could be better? (because I believe that the connection to the db is permanent when the node app is originally started?)

Note: As noted in a comment, even if there are many connections in a page, a server could scale fine, so the question should be about speed -- each image requires an independent connection which delays the showing of the image (only shown via `readfile` after connection + mysql query). Any way to prevent a new connection per script call could most likely be a good idea, if possible.

Comment: 20 database connections isn't going to break the internet, especially dependent on how expensive your query is, if it's a simple `SELECT cat_id FROM ... WHERE img_md5 = .....`.

Comment: Right, so it's more or less about my own server, but about the fact that it creates a new connection every time, which delays the showing of the image

Comment: If you don't mind me asking (*based on your edit*), why are you `readfile()`'ing the image to the browser? Is it stored as a BLOB or something? Wouldn't it be easier to just include it per HTML -> `<img src="<?php echo $the_image_path; ?>" />` ?

Comment: The script is `readfile()`ing the image back to the `src` tag. I was doing `echo $img_url` before but found out I need that `header: image` along with `readfile($img_url)`. Are you saying returning the base64 (which I create in the PHP script so I can create an image ID by md5'ing it)

Comment: That's where your expense is, not so much in the query via mysql. Is there a specific reason you're doing the base64? To prevent people finding out the directory structure?

Comment: Doing base64 so I can 1. md5 it so I get a unique ID per image right from my script and 2. I use the Google image API which requires that base64.